# Why does sum(DF) behave differently from DF.sum()?

Tags: python, pandas

In pandas 0.14, `sum(DF)` returns the sum of the headers, rather than the sum of the entries. 
Thus, one gets, for example:

```
>df = pandas.DataFrame([1,2,3])
>print(df)
   0
0  1
1  2
2  3
>sum(df)
0
```

Is there a logical reason, a use case for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

buildin function `sum()` work as:

```
sum(list(iter(df)))
```

and `iter(df)` get an iterator of column names.

you should not use buildin `sum()` for DataFrame.

Answer (score 2):

Or use `numpy.sum`:

```
In [43]:

df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3])
print 'numpy:', np.sum(df)
print '.sum() method:',df.sum()
print 'buid-in:', sum(df)
numpy: 0    6
dtype: int64
.sum() method: 0    6
dtype: int64
buid-in: 0
```